# convert date from "2009-12 Dec" format to "31-DEC-2009"

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

```
'2009-12 Dec' should be converted to '31-DEC-2009'
'2010-09 Sep' should be converted to '30-SEP-2010'
'2010-02 Feb' should be converted to '28-FEB-2010'
'2008-02 Feb' should be converted to '29-FEB-2008'
```

The values **2009-12 Dec**, **2008-02 Feb** will be displayed to the User in a drop down. The User have no option to select the **DAY**.

The user selected value should be passed to the Database. But the database expects the date in the format `DD-MMM-YYYY`. The query has '`<= USER_DATE`' condition. So, the last day of the month should be automatically selected and passed to the database.

Pl help me in writing the function that does the above job.

```
static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM MMM");

    public static String convertMapedToSqlFormat(final String maped) {
        String convertedMaped = null;
        //....
        return convertedMaped;
    }

    @Test
    public void testConvertMapedToSqlFormat() {
        String[] mapedValues = { "2009-12 Dec", "2009-11 Nov", "2009-10 Oct",
                "2009-09 Sep", "2009-08 Aug", "2009-07 Jul", "2009-06 Jun",
                "2009-05 May", "2009-04 Apr", "2009-03 Mar", "2009-02 Feb",
                "2009-01 Jan", "2008-12 Dec", "2008-11 Nov", "2008-10 Oct" };
        for (String maped : mapedValues) {
            System.out.println(convertMapedToSqlFormat(maped));
        }
    }
```

Comment: typo in your 2008 sample result there.

Comment: Really, you need to use `<` and the first day of the next month, else you lose events within the last day of the month.  Example `2009-12-31T13:00:00` should fall in the range `2009-12 Dec`, but with your method it doesn't.

Comment: @Ben <= is used. Do you think still there would be a problem?

Comment: Yes, because `2009-12-31T13:00:00 <= 2009-12-31` is false.  The correct check would be `2009-12-31T13:00:00 < 2010-01-01`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert it to [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and use [`Calendar#getActualMaximum()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29) to obtain last day of month and set the day with it.

Kickoff example:

```
String oldString = "2009-12 Dec";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").parse(oldString)); // Yes, month name is ignored but we don't need this.
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(newString); // 31-DEC-2009
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use your `DateFormat` (but fix it to `yyyy-dd MMM`) to parse the date
- convert the `Date` to `Calendar`
- Use `Calendar.getActualMaximim()`
- use `dd-MMM-yyyy` to format the obtained date.
- call `.toUpperCase()`

So:

```
static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM MMM");
static SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");

public static String convertMapedToSqlFormat(final String maped) {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(mapped);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    return dbDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toUpperCase();
}
```

A few notes:

- if possible use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) `DateTime`
- avoid having strict date formats in the database.

Comment: How do you get the last-day-of-the-month part?

Comment: small correction - return dbDateFormat.format(date.getTime()); should be return dbDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

Answer (score 1):

Get the year and month from the YYYY-MM part of the string.

Use JODA to create a point in time corresponding to the first day of that month.  Move one month forward, and one day backward.  Flatten the time to the string representation you need.

Comment: Move one month forward and use `<`, otherwise you lose any events that occur on the final day of the month at any time other than exactly midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to parse your date,
like so

```
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      Date du = new Date();
      du = df.parse(sDate);
      df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      sDate = df.format(du);
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if it does.

**PK**

Comment: There's no "day" part to parse.

Comment: Please don't LOL the answers of others.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Much easier now with the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes seen here in the Question and other Answers.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

## `YearMonth`

The [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class provides just what you want.

```
YearMonth start = YearMonth.of( 2008 , Month.OCTOBER );
YearMonth stop = YearMonth.of( 2009 , Month.DECEMBER );
List<YearMonth> yms = new ArrayList<>();
YearMonth ym = start ;
while( ! ym.isAfter( stop ) ) {
    yms.add( ym );
    // Set up the next loop.
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 ); 
}
```

To present, use a `DateTimeFormatter` to generate a String representation of the `YearMonth` value.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM MMM" );
f = f.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Or Locale.US etc.
String output = ym.format( f );
```

To get the last day of the month, interrogate the `YearMonth` object.

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

To present, use a `DateTimeFormatter`. Either let instantiate a formatter that automatically localizes appropriate to a specified `Locale`, or specify your own formatting pattern. Shown many times in many other Questions and Answers on Stack Overflow.